# URL on address bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, web

I use this script on html:

```
$(function () {
        $('table.menu a').bind('click', function (event) {

            var $anchor = $(this);

            //if you don't want to use the easing effects:
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 170
            }, 1500);

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

but I have a problem, on address bar not appears the links name...

my questions is: how can I write my anchor on address bar?

Comment: Like url/#anchor ? Remove the event.preventDefault(); to make the URL point to the href if that's the behavior that you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the links are to hashes on the page.  Like `<a href="#div2">`?  In that case, this JavaScript code is un-needed.  The browser will auto-scroll you to the element with that ID.

If you want (or for whatever reason need) to use that code, you can set `location.hash`, that will update the URL bar.

```
location.hash = $anchor.attr('href');
```